# Cannot use QPoint as QHASH key

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt5

I tried using this code:

```
QPoint pt;
QHash<QPoint, double> hexes;
hexes.contains(pt);
```

and I get the error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘qHash(const QPoint&)’
```

But if I replace 'QPoint' with 'int' it compiles just fine.  Is it possible to use QPoint as a QHash key type?

Comment: You might want to submit a feature request to the bugtracker.

Answer (score 5):

The `qHash` hashing function is not defined for `QPoint`, but you can write one using `QPair<int,int>`

```
inline uint qHash (const QPoint & key)
{
    return qHash (QPair<int,int>(key.x(), key.y()) );
}
```

Comment: Which file would this function go in?

Comment: @cid I put it in the same file I was declaring the QHash with the QPoint key in and it seems to work

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to use QPoint as a QHash key type?

According to [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qhash.html) it's possible. But you need define:

```
inline uint qHash (const QPoint & key)
```

Also `QHash` requires:

```
inline bool operator== (const QPoint & k1, const QPoint & k2)
```

but it's already defined.

Since `qHash` is already implemented for 64-bit integers I believe that this solution has sense:

```
inline uint qHash (const QPoint & key)
{
    return qHash (static_cast <qint64> (key.x () ) << 32 | key.y () );
}
```

**Note**: I don't know how to implement correct hash function which based on two 32-bit digits and output 32-bit hash.

Comment: Thx!  I'll probably use inline uint qHash(const QPoint &key)
{
        return (key.x() << 16) + key.y();
}